# How to get a similar sheet name in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find a similar sheet name in an excel using pandas.

Currently I am using below code to get dataframe of a sheet in pandas.

```
excel= pd.ExcelFile(excel)
tab_name = 'Employee'
emp_df= excel.parse(tab_name)
```

But this code will fail if the sheet name in excel contains any space or some other extra characters.

Is there any easy way to do this ?

Comment: I'd suggest to use Openpyxl for the Excel handling. Load the Excel file with openpyxl, get the list of all sheets and check their textual similarity to the name you seek ("must  start with Emp"). Then hand of the list of sheets you need to pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used similarity api (fuzzywuzzy) to find similar sheet only when sheet not found error thrown when running `excel.parse(tab_name)`

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import xlrd

try:
    tab_df = excel.parse(tab_name)
except xlrd.biffh.XLRDError:
    sheet_names=excel.sheet_names
    ratios = [fuzz.ratio(tab_name, tbname) for tbname in sheet_names]
    if(max(ratios)>50):
        tab_name = sheet_names[ratios.index(max(ratios))]
        tab_df = excel.parse(tab_name)
    else:
        logger.error(tab_name+"Not found")
```